# What new features are added in MobileFirst for hybrid application?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server, worklight-security

What new features are included as compared to worklight version 6.2 in MobileFirst for hybrid application? I searched a lot on google and IBM site I dont find any new things which are new in 7.1.0 for hybrid application. Can any one suggest new things which are included for hybrid app.

Comment: Specifically with respect to MobileFirst 7.1, you should probably take a look at the new "Cordova" app type, which is the preferred approach for building hybrid-style applications going forward: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/15/hybrid-mobile-development-and-mobilefirst-7-1-increasing-the-awesome/.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest addition in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 was **Java adapters**, enabling you to write JAX-RS applications thus creating flows not possible with JavaScript adapters.

The biggest additions in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 are the introduction of the OAuth 2.0 security model and as consequence the session-independent mode in the MobileFirst Server. Also introduced were Cordova applications (as opposed to MobileFirst Studio-managed Hybrid apps), allowing more room for applicative wizardry not possible with Hybrid apps.

For an exhaustive list of changes, see the changelogs:

7.0: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_release_notes.html?lang=en

7.1: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_release_notes.html?lang=en